# NodeJS JSON writing bug in Try Catch

Tags: javascript, node.js, json

Taking a course on NodeJS and currently learning about storing data in JSON format for a note taking app. Used a try catch block to handle errors if the .json file didn't exist. First time the catch block executes because the file is empty and the I return an empty array and store it in the JSON file. Second time also the catch block gets called when there is data in it. In the instructors video the same code works and appends the data. We are both using readFileSync function.

Using yargs for argument parsing.

What am I missing here.

Attaching code as well as app.js.

**Notes.js**

```
const getNotes = function () {
    return 'Your notes...'
}

const addNote = function(title, body){
    const notes = loadNotes()
    notes.push({
        title: title,
        body: body
    })
    saveNotes(notes)

}

const saveNotes = function(notes){
    const dataJSON = JSON.stringify(notes)
    fs.writeFileSync('notes.json', dataJSON,)
}

const loadNotes = function(){

    try{
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    } catch(e){
        return []

    }

}

module.exports = {
    getNotes: getNotes,
    addNote: addNote
}
```

**App.js**

```
const yargs = require('yargs')
const notes = require('./notes.js')

const command = process.argv[2]

yargs.version('1.1.0')

yargs.command({

    command: 'add',
    describe: 'Add a new note',
    builder: { 
        title: {
            describe: 'Note title',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        },
        body: {

            describe: 'Note body',
            demandOption: true,
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    handler: function(argv){
       notes.addNote(argv.title, argv.body)
    }
})

yargs.command({

    command: 'list',
    describe: 'Lists all notes',
    handler: function(){

        console.log('Listing notes')
    }
})

yargs.command({

    command: 'read',
    describe: 'Reads all notes',
    handler: function(){

        console.log('Reading notes')
    }
})


yargs.command({

    command: 'remove',
    describe: 'Remove a note',
    handler: function(){
        console.log('Removing note')
    }
})

yargs.parse()

//console.log(yargs.argv)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not calling `toString`, just accessing the property. Change `.toString` to `.toString()`

```
const loadNotes = function(){

    try{
        const dataBuffer = fs.readFileSync('notes.json')
        const dataJSON = dataBuffer.toString() // changed this
        return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
    } catch(e){
        return []

    }

}
```

Also, you can use `utf8` as second argument to `fs.readFileSync`, and avoid `toString()` call.

```
const dataJSON = fs.readFileSync('notes.json', 'utf8')
return JSON.parse(dataJSON)
```

Comment: That did it! How did I miss that. I was so sure it was the same code. Thank you Marcos Casagrande.

Comment: However, the utf8 as second argument isn't working. Still going into the catch block if I use that.

Comment: but did you change the variable to `dataJSON`? You'll always need the `try/catch` because `JSON.parse` throws if an invalid JSON is passed. the second argument works, you're doing something else wrong, Show the error you're getting, and `console.log(dataJSON)`

Comment: Yeah sorry, I was returning the wrong variable. Now it's working.